# How to read block data in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lot of data files. The files are structured as follows

```
1 1 2 4
1 2 2 5
1 3 5 7
.
.
.
1 n 2 6


2 1 3 4
2 2 3 6
2 3 5 9
.
.
.
2 n 7 10

3 1 32 54
3 2 4 7
3 3 9 11
.
.
.
3 n 98 102


.
.
.


m 1 2 1
m 2 4 61
m 3 5 8
.
.
.
m n 3 12
```

Each block is distant to other block by 2 vertical spaces. Ellipses here means the [usual](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375516/how-acceptable-is-an-ellipsis-in-formal-mathematics).

For each file n and m are different. How to read such data file in python and in most efficient way? Here is how gnuplot [use it](http://lowrank.net/gnuplot/datafile2-e.html) but I want to do more than that. Is there a better way or better keyword to search it because "block data python" keywords return to no good result?

Comment: The newlines seem redundant (or to make the data more human-readable); you can tell when one block ends and the next begins either by observing when the first field increases, or when the second field resets to 1. Just read and process the file line-by-line. (The file object won't actually read a single line at a time from disk; it will read larger chunks and buffer the data until you actually access it.)

Comment: Is it possible to use first and second fields as indexes (or indices)? for example if I have to find the value of 3rd column with value of 1st and 2nd?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.